# WM_CONCAT with DISTINCT Clause - Compiled Package versus Stand-Alone Query Issue

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I was writing some program that uses the WM_CONCAT function.  When I run this query:

```
SELECT WM_CONCAT(DISTINCT employee_id)
FROM   employee
WHERE  ROWNUM < 20;
```

It works fine.  When I try to compile the relatively same query in a package function or procedure, it produces this error:  PL/SQL: ORA-30482: DISTINCT option not allowed for this function

```
FUNCTION fetch_raw_data_by_range
RETURN VARCHAR2 IS

    v_some_string VARCHAR2(32000);

BEGIN

    SELECT WM_CONCAT(DISTINCT employee_id)
    INTO   v_some_string
    FROM   employee
    WHERE  ROWNUM < 20;

    RETURN v_some_string;

END;
```

I realize WM_CONCAT is not officially supported, but can someone explain why it would work as a stand alone query with DISTINCT, but not compile in a package?

Comment: You should be able to get similar results with the LISTAGG function.

Comment: I tagged this as oracle10g, which does not provide that function

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Problem is that WM_CONCAT is stored procedure written on pl/sql.

There is a open bug #9323679: PL/SQL CALLING A USER DEFINED AGGREGRATE FUNCTION WITH DISTINCT FAILS ORA-30482.

Workaround for problems like this is using dynamic sql.

So if you wrap your query in

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE '<your_query>';
```

Then it should work.

But as OldProgrammer has suggested already, you better avoid using this WM_CONCAT at all.

Comment: Can you provide a link to documentation describing this behavior?

Comment: @Reimus Sorry, it seems I'm a bit mixed up this issue with the new 11g behavior. I'm fixing this answer.

Comment: Ah, so it is a bug and not due to some functional requirement.  Thanks for the reference material.  I don't have access to their tracker, but I was able to find more posts related to the bug number.

Answer (score 5):

PL/SQL will not let you to use `distinct` in an aggregated function, and this issue shows that the SQL-engine and the PL/SQL-engine do not use the same parser.

One of the solutions to this problem is to use sub query as below,

```
SELECT WM_CONCAT(employee_id)
INTO   v_some_string
FROM   (select DISTINCT employee_id
        FROM   employee)
WHERE  ROWNUM < 20;
```

Another solution is to use dynamic SQL as Nagh suggested,

```
FUNCTION fetch_raw_data_by_range
RETURN VARCHAR2 IS

    v_some_string VARCHAR2(32000);
    v_sql VARCHAR2(200);

BEGIN

    v_sql :='SELECT WM_CONCAT(DISTINCT employee_id)
             FROM   employee
             WHERE  ROWNUM < 20';

    execute immediate v_sql INTO v_some_string;
    RETURN v_some_string;
END;
```

Comment: I realize that the pl/sql parser is not the same as the query parser, but what I really want to know is why it happens, i.e. what's the rule in place that causes this behavior.  It's possible that there's a good reason DISTINCT is not allowed in some specific scenario in pl/sql of which my example here is a subset example and not representative of the 'issue' as a whole.