# Concatenate rows, based on common column Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, concatenation

I have to concatenate below data

```
a b c  
1 Text 22-03-2015
1 Text1 22-03-2015
2 Text2 24-05-2015
3 Text5 29-05-2015
1 Text11 23-03-2015
```

And the expected Output is

```
a b c
1 Text,text1 22-03-2015
1 Text11 23-03-2016
2 Text2 24-05-2015
3 Text5 29-05-2015
```

Tried wm_concat function and it works but i cant remove the duplicates from the data and usage of **LISTAGG** results in error

> "ora-01489 result of string concatenation is too long in oracle"

error as columns b contains values greater than 4000 characters.
Any alternatives apart form these 2 functions?

Comment: One option would be to use a subquery with `distinct`.  This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19577257/wm-concat-with-distinct-clause-compiled-package-versus-stand-alone-query-issue

Comment: Distinct isn't working. This query itself is a subquery.

Comment: It's not clear why from your sample data.  You should provide sample data that illustrates the problem you are having.  Perhaps create a sqlfiddle.com to demonstrate.

Comment: SELECT a
              ,to_char(c,'DD.MM.YYYY') enddate
              ,type
              ,wm_concat( type || ': (' || to_char (c,'HH:MI:SS AM') || ') ' || b ) output
          FROM table
         GROUP BY a
                 ,to_char(c,'DD.MM.YYYY') 
                 ,type

Comment: Is the subquery i'm using

Comment: Thank you @sgeddes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**`LISTAGG`**](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030) function if you are `Oracle 11g+`

```
SELECT a, LISTAGG(b, ' ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY b) as b, c
FROM   yourtable
GROUP BY a,c;
```

Comment: Does LISTAGG Function has limit of 4000 characters in Oracle 12c?

Comment: @AnnieJeba Yes when string is longer than 4000 bytes it will limit the result. Check this answer for more info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13795220/listagg-function-result-of-string-concatenation-is-too-long